# Why incrementor is printing 3 even condition is checking for less then 3?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

for below code output will print "3" for 3 times, i.e updates same variable for 3 times

```
for(var k=0;k<3;k++){
 setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(k)
    },1000) 
}
```

similarly if i use let instead of var 1,2,3

```
for(var k=0;k<3;k++){
 setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(k)
    },1000) 
}
```

i know why it prints 0,1,2 as i is different every time. i'm just wondering why its printing 3 in case of var as condition is to checking for less then 3?

Comment: read this https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md

Comment: and this https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure

Comment: you have pasted the exact same code in both snippets.

Comment: please have a look to duplicate target 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

The above result is because, var defines variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

let creates a variable declaration for each loop which is block level declaration. So basically it creates a scope within { }.

If you want to print using var keyword use self invoked functions :

for(var k=0;k<3;k++){

(function(k){

```
 setTimeout(()=>{

      console.log(k)

    },1000) 

})(k);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the function `setTimeout` will execute after the delay provided. The code execution doesn't stop since the javascript is based on concurrency model and [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), so the execution continues till the delay provided. which in case, increment the k. Also, the post-increment operator will use the value before iteration. So, for last iteration the value of k is 3, but since we have given a delay, it would print 3 every time.